# Programmatically set DLL search path in VBA macro

Tags: vba, dll, ms-word

**The problem**

- I have a word template which uses VBA's `Declare` statement to link to a dll, whose path can be determined within the VBA macro
- I want to delploy this to the users %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Word\STARTUP directory
- I DON'T want to permanently change the user's PATH environment variable (temporarily would be OK, but this doesn't seem to work as they don't get refreshed until application restart)

**Attempted solution**

I tried dynamically adding the code with the `Declare` statements using `ThisDocument.VBProject.CodeModule.AddFromString(code)` which works when loading the template from a normal directory, but when the template is within Word\STARTUP, it gives the following error:

> Run-time error '50289':
>
> Can't perform operation since the
>   project is protected.

And setting the registry key "HKEY___LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Word\Security\AccessVBOM" to 1 doesn't fix this when the template is in Word\STARTUP

---

I'm really struggling to find a solution. If anyone knows a way to do this, that would be great.

Comment: Related for MSAccess http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28977285/how-do-i-find-the-current-path-directory-of-a-ms-access-database

Answer (score 11):

Frankly, I don't know what's the problem with using all those VBA code injection, assembly generation for LoadLibrary() calls, etc techniques that I've seen used for this simple task. In my project I use simple code to load dll from the same location as the workbook, like this:

```
Declare Function MyFunc Lib "MyDll.dll" (....) As ...

Sub Test()
  ....
  ChDir ActiveWorkbook.Path
  ... = MyFunc(....)
End Sub
```

Excel 2003 at least, has no problem loading the dll from the current path, Set ChDir to whatever path your DLL has. You might also need to change your current drive which is separate from current path. You have to do it only once, before the first function call, after it the DLL stays attached no matter where your current path is, so you may do it once in workbook_open and not bother about the path later. I provide an empty dummy function in the DLL just for this pupose. I don't think MS Word is any different on this.

```
Private Declare Sub Dummy Lib "MyDLL.dll" ()

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ChDrive Left$(Me.Path, 1)
    ChDir Me.Path
    Dummy
End Sub
```

Comment: Ha, such a brilliantly elegant solution to an otherwise complicated problem, thanks! :D

Comment: That won't always work. Current directory is a long way down the list of paths that are searched, and in some scenarios the current directory may not be one the search path at all. Plus you are screwing with the process wide working directory. The explicit `LoadLibrary` approach with an absolute path is the best way to do this.

Comment: Assuming you need the current path for an Access file instead of Excel, its `CurrentProject.Path`

Answer (score 6):

You can use LoadLibrary api.

For example in my projects the code looks like this:

```
If LibraryLoaded() Then
   Call MyFunc ...
End If


Public Function LibraryLoaded() As Boolean

 Static IsLoaded As Boolean
 Static TriedToLoadAlready As Boolean

 If TriedToLoadAlready Then
    LibraryLoaded = IsLoaded
    Exit Function
  End If
  Dim path As String
 path = VBAProject.ThisWorkbook.path
 path = Left(path, InStrRev(path, "\") - 1)
 IsLoaded = LoadLibrary(path & "\bin\" & cLibraryName)
 TriedToLoadAlready = True

 LibraryLoaded = IsLoaded

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

There is another really really ugly solution, but this blogger figured it out, and I can't figure out any other way:

http://blogs.msdn.com/pranavwagh/archive/2006/08/30/How-To-Load-Win32-dlls-Dynamically-In-VBA.aspx

Basically, you write a procedure that creates a code module in VBA during runtime.  This module must create a reference to the dll and it must create a dummy function (or procedure) as part of this module that calls the dll.  Then, from your code, you use Application.Run(dummyfunction(), arg1, arg2...).  This is necessary because otherwise, the project will not compile because dummyfunction isn't yet a function.

You'll notice in his code, he uses InputBox() to get the location of the .dll but obviously you could get the location from a range in the spreadsheet.  The following code snippet may be useful.

```
Dim cm As CodeModule
Dim vbc As VBComponent

Set cm = Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_StdModule).CodeModule
cm.AddFromString (decString & funcString)
cm.Name = "MyNewModule"
Set vbc = cm.Parent
Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Remove vbc
```

'decString' and 'funcString' were just strings I constructed like his 'ss'.  The snippet shows how you can rename the code module so that you could delete it later if needed.  Obviously, this just deletes it right after it is created, and you probably wouldn't want to do that, but at least it shows you how it would be done.

Having said all that, we mostly just write .exe's now and shell out.  If you need VBA to wait on the shell to finish, there are solutions for that issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing, using Pranav Wagh's methodology linked above and code from C Pearson's site (http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx).  This code prompts the user to select the path to the dll using an Open File window, builds a new module with a Declare Function with the inputted path and a function to execute a handshake with the dll.  The purpose-built function in the dll returns a 1 if successful:

```
Public rtn As Integer

Sub LinkToDll()

Dim path As String, default As String
MsgBox "Select Geo_DLL.dll file from next window"

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Select Geo_DLL.dll file"
    If .Show = True Then
        path = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End With

'Add a module
Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent

Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_StdModule)
VBComp.Name = "LinkModule"

'Add procedure to module
Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
Dim LineNum As Long

Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents("LinkModule")
Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule

With CodeMod
LineNum = .CountOfLines + 1
.InsertLines LineNum, "Declare Function RegDll Lib " & Chr(34) & path & Chr(34) & " (ByRef rtn As Integer)"
LineNum = LineNum + 1
.InsertLines LineNum, "Sub runthisfunc(rtn)"
LineNum = LineNum + 1
.InsertLines LineNum, "On Error Resume Next"
LineNum = LineNum + 1
.InsertLines LineNum, "rtn = 0"
LineNum = LineNum + 1
.InsertLines LineNum, "RegDll rtn"
LineNum = LineNum + 1
.InsertLines LineNum, "If rtn = 1 Then MsgBox (" & Chr(34) & "DLL linked" & Chr(34) & ")"
LineNum = LineNum + 1
.InsertLines LineNum, "If rtn = 0 Then MsgBox (" & Chr(34) & "DLL not found" & Chr(34) & ")"
LineNum = LineNum + 1
.InsertLines LineNum, "End Sub"
End With

'This is what CodeMod.InsertLines is writing:
'--------------------------------------------
'Declare Function RegDll Lib "C:\path\Geo_DLL.dll" (ByRef rtn As Integer)
'Sub runthisfunc(rtn)
'On Error Resume Next
'rtn = 0
'RegDll rtn
'If rtn = 1 Then MsgBox ("DLL Linked")
'If rtn = 0 Then MsgBox (DLL not found")
'End Sub

Application.Run "runthisfunc", rtn

'Delete Module
VBProj.VBComponents.Remove VBComp

End Sub
```

However, once I turned the workbook (xlsm) into an addin (xlam) I found that Excel wouldn't let the macro create new modules so my LinkToDll wouldn't work.  The fix was to put the Declare Function back into LinkToDll with just the dll file name ("Geo_DLL.dll") as the Lib along with the runthisfunc sub.  I found having the user simply select the dll file via the Open File window was enough to point Excel to the dll even with only the file name in the Lib portion of the Declare Function statement.

Chris

Answer (score 0):

In my case code below worked. I added "ChDir (ThisWorkbook.Path)"
after function. But I tested it only on my laptop. I don't know if it works on network.

```
Option Explicit
' Declare the function that is in the DLL
Private Declare PtrSafe Function suntransitForEXL Lib _
"sampadll.dll" (ByRef lat As Double, ByRef lon As Double, ByRef dy As Integer, ByRef mnt As Integer, ByRef yr As Integer, ByRef tmz As Double) As Double
' use function on worksheet
Function noon(latitude As Double, longtitude As Double, day As Integer, month As Integer, year As Integer, timezone As Double) As Double
ChDir (ThisWorkbook.Path) ' Set working directory to current.
Dim decimaltime As Double
Dim hour As Integer
Dim minute As Integer
Dim second As Integer
decimaltime = suntransitForEXL(latitude, longtitude, day, month, year, timezone)
hour = Fix(decimaltime)
minute = Fix((decimaltime - hour) * 60)
second = Fix(((decimaltime - hour) * 60 - minute) * 60)
noon = TimeSerial(hour, minute, second)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Use two Windows APIs to set & restore a temporary environment variable path for the current process and load/unload the library at runtime using two more APIs, again, for the running process only:

```vb
#If Mac Then

    ' Third-party DLL
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function MyFunction Lib "MyLib.dylib" (ByVal arg As String) As Long
    
    ' Write a similar procedure to call using the macOS method with the dylib in the Office sandbox
    
#Else

    ' Third-party DLL
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function MyFunction Lib "MyLib.dll" (ByVal arg As String) As Long
    
    ' Library loader API functions
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetEnvironmentVariable Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetEnvironmentVariableA" ( _
                                     ByVal lpName As String, _
                                     ByVal lpBuffer As String, _
                                     ByVal nSize As Long) As Long

    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetEnvironmentVariable Lib "kernel32" Alias "SetEnvironmentVariableA" ( _
                                     ByVal lpName As String, _
                                     ByVal lpValue As String) As Long
                                     
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function LoadLibrary Lib "kernel32" Alias "LoadLibraryA" ( _
                                     ByVal lpLibFileName As String) As LongPtr
                                     
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FreeLibrary Lib "kernel32" ( _
                                     ByVal hLibModule As LongPtr) As Long
    
    ' Call a third-party DLL function in a dynamic folder,
    ' installed in the user profile of the file system.
    Sub TestDLL()
        Dim hLib As LongPtr                 ' Handle to the DLL
        Dim PathToDLL As String             ' Folder where the DLL is installed
        Const DLL_FILENAME = "MyLib.dll"    ' Filename of the DLL
    
        PathToDLL = Environ("APPDATA") & "\Microsoft\AddIns\MyApp\"

        ' Save the current PATH environment variable
        CurPath = GetCurrentEnvironmentPath

        ' Overwrite the environment variable stored in the current process
        SetEnvironmentVariable "PATH", PathToDLL
    
        ' Load the specified DLL into the address space of the calling process
        hLib = LoadLibrary(DLL_FILENAME)
    
        ' Call the function in the third-party library
        Debug.Print MyFunction("test")
        
        ' Unload the specified DLL from the address space of the calling process
        Call FreeLibrary(hLib)

        ' Restore the original environment PATH
        ' SetEnvironmentVariable "PATH", CurPath
    End Sub

    Private Function GetProcessEnvironmentPath() As String
        Dim buffer As String
        
        ' Max size = 32,767 characters, including null-terminating character
        buffer = String(32767 - 1, "*") & vbNull
        
        Call GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", buffer, Len(buffer))
        
        GetProcessEnvironmentPath = Left(buffer, InStr(1, buffer, "*") - 1)
    End Function

#End If
```

Comment: Setting the PATH variable is against the OP's intention to not set the PATH variable, and doing so is [unnecessary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53052106/11683). It's probably also worth mentioning in the answer that the entire thing (somewhat confusingly) works [only because](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53025569/loadlibrary-does-not-recognize-path-in-vba-code#comment92953218_53025569) the loaded libraries are compared on the module names only, not full paths, so manually loading a library from any path affects the `Declare` definitions that use that file name.

Comment: The OP stated temporary would be ok and since this does not change it for the system but for the calling process only, this seems to answer the need. I'm thinking about your other comments!

Comment: It screws up the process until it's restarted though. Its entire PATH variable is emptied and replaced with just one folder. And it's entire MS Word we're talking about, something is bound to break. Especially so given that each document appears as a separate window, but actually they are all the same process, so the user will have to close all documents to fix that.

Comment: Hmmm. I guess you could restore it after the DLL function call. I tried the AddDllDirectory and found that you also need to call SetDefaultDllDirectories with the flag LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_USER_DIRS if using LoadLibraryA. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @GSerg comments for [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77218140/2674672), here's an alternative method that doesn't touch the processes' PATH environment variable and instead adds a temporary path the the DLL search path for the running process:

```
Option Explicit

#If Mac Then

    ' Third-party DLL
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function MyFunction Lib "MyLib.dylib" (ByVal arg As String) As Long
    
    ' Write a similar procedure to call using the macOS method with the dylib in the Office sandbox
    
#Else

    ' Third-party DLL
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function MyFunction Lib "MyLib.dll" (ByVal arg As String) As Long
    
    ' Library loader API functions
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetDefaultDllDirectories Lib "kernel32" ( _
                                     ByVal dwFlags As Long) As LongPtr
    
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function AddDllDirectory Lib "kernel32" ( _
                                     ByVal lpLibDirectory As String) As LongPtr
                                     
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function RemoveDllDirectory Lib "kernel32" ( _
                                     ByVal lpCookie As LongPtr) As LongPtr
                                     
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function LoadLibrary Lib "kernel32" Alias "LoadLibraryA" ( _
                                     ByVal lpLibFileName As String) As LongPtr
                                     
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FreeLibrary Lib "kernel32" ( _
                                     ByVal hLibModule As LongPtr) As Long
    
    ' Call a third-party DLL function in a dynamic folder,
    ' installed in the user profile of the file system.
    Sub TestDLL()
        Dim lpCookie As LongPtr             ' Reference to the added DLL directory path
        Dim hLib As LongPtr                 ' Handle to the DLL
        Dim PathToDLL As String             ' Folder where the DLL is installed
        Const DLL_FILENAME = "MyLib.dll"    ' Filename of the DLL
    
        PathToDLL = Environ("APPDATA") & "\Microsoft\AddIns\MyApp\"

        Const LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_USER_DIRS = &H1000&
        
        ' Required if adding a DLL directory before calling LoadLibraryA
        Call SetDefaultDllDirectories(LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_USER_DIRS)
        
        ' Add a directory to the process DLL search path
        lpCookie = AddDllDirectory(StrConv(PathToDLL, vbUnicode))
        
        ' Load the specified DLL into the address space of the calling process
        hLib = LoadLibrary(DLL_FILENAME)
    
        ' Call the function in the third-party library
        Debug.Print MyFunction("test")
        
        ' Unload the specified DLL from the address space of the calling process
        Call FreeLibrary(hLib)

        ' Remove the DLL directory added above
        Call RemoveDllDirectory(lpCookie)
        
    End Sub


#End If
```