# Compile a dll that supports declare function in VBA

Tags: c#, c++, .net, vba, dll

SO newb here so feel free to let me know of any etiquette violations!

I am new to library compilation and have been researching (mostly on this forum) building libraries that can be referenced from office and other programs supporting vba scripting.  I have found a few good answers.  I have successfully executed the solution from this thread:

[A Simple C# DLL - how do I call it from Excel, Access, VBA, VB6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170794/a-simple-c-sharp-dll-how-do-i-call-it-from-excel-access-vba-vb6)

which involves creating an instance of a C# class in VBA and then calling a method of the class (the dll must be 'regasm'ed).  I am very interested in the solution outlined on this thread:

[Programmatically set DLL search path in VBA macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450177/programmatically-set-dll-search-path-in-vba-macro/)

in which the top upvoted answer (from Panda-34) seems to show a means to use a pure Declare Function rather than object creation.  If I understand Panda's answer correctly, this method is able to load a dll into the vba project without setting a reference in tools->references (it employs a nifty trick with ChDir).

I am able to get the DeclareFunction to pass the vba compilaton, but when execution gets to a line using the function, I get a "Cannot determine entry point" type message.  All the forum solutions to this error involve using regasm to register the classes in the dll and then set a reference so that an instance of the class can be created.  My questions are:

1) In Panda's solution does the dll still need regasm?

2) Is using C# to implement this solution impossible because C# functions are always wrapped in classes?  I have been starting to wonder whether the problem is that you cannot Declare Function on a method that is not visible at the global level of the dll because it may be ambiguous - Class1 and Class2 in Test.dll may both have a HelloWorld() member.  If that is the case, I like C++ better anyway (my machine has csc and not cl so I've been learning some C#).

I'm sorry if I should not have started a new thread for this question.  I am brand new to SO, so I don't have permission to comment on Panda's answer, and it specifically says not to ask another question about someone's answer with your answer, so I took that to mean start a new thread...

Answer (score 0):

C# does not support all features of MSIL. Global functions is one of them. So AFAIK you can't have global functions in C#, it's just not part of the language. You need Managed C++ for ex. 
As for my experience, the best way is to use COM friendly c# assembly registered with regasm and the codebase switch.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the input, you are right.  I know that it does not support global functions.  I was asking if that means that you cannot Declare Function to a C# dll.  If you Declare Function to MyClass.HelloWorld(), the VBA compiler does not like the dot.  I'm curious, because on every other forum I read, people said you could not Declare Function to your own dll, only to Microsoft API dlls.  However, in the second link above, Panda says he could do it, and he got 2 up votes and some good comments thanking him, so I think his method works.  I want to try it with a C++ dll.