# How do I find the current path (directory) of a MS Access database?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am writing VBA within my Access database and I need to reference the containing directory of this database. This path could change since I will be moving the database around.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You will want to use the following code:

```
CurrentProject.Path
```

This will return a string representing the file path of the current directory.

Comment: And in case you want the full path including file name:
CurrentProject.Path & "\" & CurrentProject.Name

Comment: If you wanted the full path and file name you could just use `CurrentProject.FullName`