# LoadLibrary does not recognize PATH in VBA code

Tags: vba, interop, windows-store, loadlibrary

I have a DLL and I need to call it using `LoadLibrary("func1.dll")`. The full path of `func1.dll` is omitted from `LoadLibrary` because I have to set the `PATH` variable to the place where `func1.dll` resides, since `func1.dll` references another DLL called `func2.dll`.

So, in order to get this to work I use the following code:

```
Private Declare Function FreeLibrary Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hLibModule As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function LoadLibrary Lib "kernel32" Alias "LoadLibraryA" (ByVal lpLibFileName As String) As Long
Private Declare Function SetEnvironmentVariable Lib "kernel32" Alias "SetEnvironmentVariableA" (ByVal lpName As String, ByVal lpValue As String) As Long

Private Sub t1()
    Dim lb As Long
    Dim dllpath As String

    dllpath = "C:\temp\DllsOffice\DLLsOffice\Debug"
    SetEnvironmentVariable "PATH", dllpath 
    Debug.Print Environ("PATH")

    lb = LoadLibrary("func1.dll")
    MsgBox lb   

    FreeLibrary lb
End Sub
```

which works perfectly fine for VBA of Offices 2007, 2010, 2013, 2016 even the Office 2019. 32 and 64 bits.

The problem arises when writing the above code in VBA of the Office installed from Microsoft Store:
[image]

When running the above VBA code in Office from Microsoft Store the line:

```
LoadLibrary("func1.dll")
```

returns 0, meaning that the DLL was not loaded. So, I ran out of ideas in order to get this to work, but with no success til now.

Here are some additional information about the problem and what I've tried to do:

1. Copying the DLL to executable path. For instance, if I place`func1.dll` (and `func2.dll`) in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14` I can use `LoadLibrary`without the need of using `SetEnvironmentVariable "PATH", dllpath`. But I cannot copy the DLL to the path of Office from Microsoft Store `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.Office.Desktop.Word_16040.10827.20181.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Office16` because it gives access denied;
2. I completely sure that `SetEnvironmentVariable "PATH", dllpath` is working fine on Office from Microsoft Store. I tested this putting an executable inside the `C:\temp\DllsOffice\DLLsOffice\Debug` and then calling `Shell "test.exe"` (without passing the full path) my `test.exe` program is opened normally.

Do you what I'm missing or have any ideas for me to follow? Thanks you all.

Comment: You are correct that [store apps ignore `PATH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#standard-search-order-for-windows-store-apps), and "*If a DLL has dependencies, the system searches for the dependent DLLs as if they were loaded with just their module names. This is true even if the first DLL was loaded by specifying a full path"*.

Comment: But, [*"If a DLL with the same module name is already loaded in memory, the system uses the loaded DLL, no matter which directory it is in. The system does not search for the DLL"*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#search-order-for-windows-store-apps), so try loading all dependent DLLs explicitly with `LoadLibrary` first using full paths.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @GSerg. Actually, loading the `func2.dll` first and then `func1.dll` worked partially. Using the function `SetDllDirectoryA` from kernel32 did the same effect (worked partially). The problem is that at some point of the application another DLL from a different path (not know previously) is called and an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a solution using the function `AddDllDirectory`. According to the [Microsoft website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-adddlldirectory), the `AddDllDirectory` function:

> Adds a directory to the process DLL search path.

That means, differently from `SetDllDirectory` which replaces the DLL search path, `AddDllDirectory` works like an incremental DLL search path. So, my working code can be something like this:

```
Private Declare Function FreeLibrary Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hLibModule As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function LoadLibrary Lib "kernel32" Alias "LoadLibraryA" (ByVal lpLibFileName As String) As Long
Private Declare Function SetEnvironmentVariable Lib "kernel32" Alias "SetEnvironmentVariableA" (ByVal lpName As String, ByVal lpValue As String) As Long
Private Declare Function AddDllDirectory Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpLibFileName As String) As Integer

Private Sub t1()
    Dim lb As Long
    Dim dllpath1 As String
    Dim dllpath2 As String
    Dim dllpathN As String

    dllpath1 = "C:\temp\DllsOffice\DLLsOffice\Debug1"
    dllpath2 = "C:\temp\OtherPath"
    dllpathN = "C:\temp\EvenOtherPath"
    AddDllDirectory (StrConv(dllpath1, vbUnicode))
    AddDllDirectory (StrConv(dllpath2, vbUnicode))
    AddDllDirectory (StrConv(dllpathN, vbUnicode))

    lb = LoadLibrary("func1.dll")  ' Success :)
    MsgBox lb   

    FreeLibrary lb
End Sub
```

OBS: The trick thing with the `AddDllDirectory` in VBA is that there is not an Ansi nor Unicode version of that function to be used like:

```
AddDllDirectoryA for Ansi 
AddDllDirectoryW for Unicode
```

So I needed to use the function `StrConv` to explict convert the path to the Unicode format.