# VBA: how to set a dynamic library path for declare statement?

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, dll, path

I have a program in Excel's VBA that need to call some methods from a DLL, both are under my control in term of code development. I need to be able to select what DLL library (from various releases) should be used at runtime, but the Declare statement from VBA only allow for constants in the Lib path.

The objective is multiple :

1. Be able to select the library release at runtime from one Excel workbook
2. Ease the code maintenance because a lot of library methods are used, meaning a lot of Declare statement to be edited when library path is changed
3. Search dynamically at runtime the library from various predefined locations, to comply with deployment purposes. In dev environment, the library is in a dev directory, but for end-users, the library could be in 3 various locations: the workbook path, a specific directory on the computer, or a specific directory from a network drive.

I tried to declare the path in Public Const variable, but it doesn't works:

```
' This work
Private Declare PtrSafe Function addAmplifier Lib "path\to\lib.dll" (...) As Integer

' This don't work
Public Const libPath As String = "path\to\lib.dll"
Private Declare PtrSafe Function addAmplifier Lib libPath (...) As Integer
```

Is there a hijack way to use a variable in the Declare statement ? Or is there a way to create a VBA module able to edit the VBA code of the second module where the Declare statements are located in, and replace with regexp all occurrences of a String, save the VBA project then execute the module ? More formally : can VBA code rewrite itself at runtime ?

Comment: _More formally: can VBA code rewrite itself at runtime?_ In short: Yes: http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/vbe.aspx But it is not really recommended, as it is a potential attack path... Also, it is likely that anti-virus software will flag the code.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, so this is not a way where I want to go : my application must be safe, and will run on computers with corporate antivirus software and I can't manage the whitelist.

Comment: Maybe this solution could help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/11175105/10223558

Comment: Changing the working directory... interesting solution, I'll try, thanks

Comment: Access to the VBA project OM is turned off by default in the Trust Center (File / Options / Trust Center / Trust Center Settings / Macro Settings) and you probably shouldn't try to change the corresponding registry setting as it can be controlled via policy.

Comment: This can easily be unlocked either by a registry edit (I handled this using the post-install script of the installer I built), or to ask end-users to trust the application directory itself. This can be done via Excel setup and can easily be documented in a user-guide. If this is blocked by a domain policy, so you'll have either to have your installer allowed to run with admin privileges, or to ask your IT department to allow it for your product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by *L8n*, the solution to change the working directory works fine.

So if the libraries are located in a sub-folder into the workbook path, we can do the following process each time a DLL native function is called :

1. Change the working directory to go into the sub-folder with `ChDir()`
2. Execute the native function
3. Go back to the parent folder with `ChDir()`

However, I suspect the Frequent call of `ChDir()` could slow down the VBA execution since it also seems to update the execution context with some hidden variables from the VBA runtime.

Comment: I can't get this to work. And if it does work, why put the dll files in a sub-folder rather than the same folder as the workbook? Does anyone know where VBA looks for DLLs and in what order e.g. CurDir, PATH, other?

Comment: Hi, This solution works fine. It's not very clean, but at least it works. VBA is executed inside Excel runtime, so the first DLL lookup directory is the Excel installation directory in program files. The second one is the path where your workbook is located, and after, like all classic softwares, the %PATH% and default OS directories are used.

Comment: @MaëlLeMonnier posted a late answer to your question based on conditional compilation you might find helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I found that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53025569/loadlibrary-does-not-recognize-path-in-vba-code) that involves the WinAPI LoadLibrary function works. And here it is updated for VBA7:

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function MyFunction Lib "MyLib.dll" () 
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetEnvironmentVariable Lib "kernel32" Alias "SetEnvironmentVariableA" (ByVal lpName As String, ByVal lpValue As String) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function LoadLibrary Lib "kernel32" Alias "LoadLibraryA" (ByVal lpLibFileName As String) As LongPtr
    Declare PtrSafe Function FreeLibrary Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hLibModule As LongPtr) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function MyFunction Lib "MyLib.dll" ()
    Private Declare Function SetEnvironmentVariable Lib "kernel32" Alias "SetEnvironmentVariableA" (ByVal lpName As String, ByVal lpValue As String) As Long
    Private Declare Function LoadLibrary Lib "kernel32" Alias "LoadLibraryA" (ByVal lpLibFileName As String) As Long
    Private Declare Function FreeLibrary Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hLibModule As Long) As Long
#End If

Private Sub TestDLL()
#If VBA7 Then
    Dim hLib As LongPtr.   ' Handle to DLL library
#Else
    Dim hLib As Long
#End If
    Dim pathToDLL As String

    pathToDLL = Environ("APPDATA") & "\Microsoft\AddIns\MyApp"
    
    Call SetEnvironmentVariable ("PATH", pathToDLL)

    hLib = LoadLibrary("MyLib.dll")

    Call MyFunction

    Call FreeLibrary(hLib)
End Sub
```

Comment: This gave me the solution to a problem  I had- seet https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77375944/dll-declaration-with-not-fixed-path/77380086#77380086

 Brilliant but it should be Win64 (to differ in 32 bit 64 bit excel versions) and not VB7 (these kind of Excel Versions should not be used anymore Excel 2003?) in my humble opinion. 
But thanks again for this brilliant help.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a *directory hopping* for different user types (dev|end-user) you might profit from **conditional compilation**; as the needed library paths need to be written literally within the declarations themselves, this allows to hide the unneeded declaration(s) from the compiler within an #If...Then... #ElseIf...Then #Else #End If directive:

**A) via compiler constant**

```
Option Explicit
'>> Change conditional UserType constant (manually) as required <<
#Const UserType = "dev"     ' alternatively: .. = "end"

'Conditional compilation of compiler constant
#If UserType = "dev" Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function addAmplifier Lib "path\to\dev\lib.dll" (...) As Integer
#Else
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function addAmplifier Lib "path\to\end\lib.dll" (...) As Integer
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function specific Lib "path\to\specific\lib.dll" (...) As Integer
#End If
```

**B) via conditional compilation argument in the project's properties**

A quite similar way would be to define a conditional compilation argument (e.g. `UserType = "dev") directly in the
Visual Basic Editor's menu:

> Tools >VBAProject|xyProject Properties > Conditional Compilation arguments

[image: VBAProject properties...]
*or by right-clicking the (VBA)project and its properties from the Project Explorer pane*.

**Further Links**

- [Compiler constants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Concepts/Getting-Started/compiler-constants)
- [Conditional compilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-conditional-compilation)
- [Conditional compilation expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/microsoft_general_purpose_programming_languages/ms-vbal/efd3d84d-0d78-4456-882e-8422cf2938a5?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [How to programmatically change conditional compilation properties of a VBA project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726791/how-to-programmatically-change-conditional-compilation-properties-of-a-vba-proje)