# Dll Declaration with not fixed path

Tags: vba

In an vba project I need access to a custom dll.
The problem is, that I do not want to register the MyDll in system32 or syswow64.
(The dll has not to be registered and it makes distributing easier this way)

But if I have to reference it, I need a fixed path like shown in code.
But that makes it necessary, that the dll is placed exactly in this folder.
(And one can ignore the else part today):
Example Code

```
Option Explicit
Option Private Module
#If Win64 Then
Public Declare PtrSafe Function foo Lib "C:\Folder1\DeepFolder\MyDll.dll" (ByVal FileName As String) As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function bar Lib "C:\Folder1\DeepFolder\MyDll.dll" (ByVal session As Long, ByVal fieldname As String, ByVal Value As String) As Long
#Else
Public Declare Function foo Lib "C:\Folder1\DeepFolder\vpmsdl32.dll" (ByVal FileName As String) As Long
Public Declare Function bar Lib "C:\Folder1\DeepFolder\vpmsdl32.dll" (ByVal session As Long, ByVal fieldname As String, ByVal Value As String) As Long
#End If
```

I would prefer to have the path C:\Folder1\DeepFolder\ relativ.
E.G.

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Function foo Lib AVariableWithPath & "\MyDll.dll" (ByVal FileName As String) As Long
```

Where AVariableWithPath is any path.
But until now, I could not find a way, and I think, it is not possible.
But perhaps I'm wrong.

Thank you for any answer.

Comment: Maybe look at - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77217033/478884

Comment: @TimWilliams This looks at least promising. I will need a few days next week to check it with the given dll and with the needed functionality.  I will tell, if it worked. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks again, I had to test it today i was just to nosy and it really worked!
I give the complete solution in the anser part. I hope this is okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/77217033/478884 I could solve this problem. But I want to give my solution to everybody as an example without sense cause I can not show the real code but it should help (You have to adapt it to your code).
In the class module the dll calls are handled. In the Class_Initialize the path to the dll is set and in Class_Terminate it is released.

In mdlApis are the necessary Api declarations in my Example my dll has 4 different calls. In my Example there are different Dlls for 32 and 64 bit Excel. Of course these dlls have to be at the given place.

In mdlIni the Class Variable is set and released.
In my project this worked!

Modul mdlApis

```
Option Explicit
Option Private Module

' Win64 is for 64 bit Excel  VBA7 is useless today
#If Win64 Then
Public Declare PtrSafe Function dllFunc1 Lib "MyDll64.dll" (ByVal FileName As String) As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function dllFunc2 Lib "MyDll64.dll" (ByVal session As Long, ByVal fieldname As String, ByVal Value As String) As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function dllFunc3 Lib "MyDll64.dll" (ByVal session As Long, ByVal context As String, ByVal result As String, ByVal result_buffer_size As Long, ByVal message As String, ByVal message_buffer_size As Long, ByVal fieldref As String, ByVal fieldref_buffer_size As Long) As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function dllFunc4 Lib "MyDll64.dll" (ByVal session As Long, ByVal context As String, ByVal fieldname As String, ByVal result As String, ByVal result_buffer_size As Long, ByVal message As String, ByVal message_buffer_size As Long, ByVal fieldref As String, ByVal fieldref_buffer_size As Long) As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function dllFunc5 Lib "MyDll64.dll" (ByVal session As Long) As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function SetEnvironmentVariable Lib "kernel32" Alias "SetEnvironmentVariableA" (ByVal lpName As String, ByVal lpValue As String) As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function LoadLibrary Lib "kernel32" Alias "LoadLibraryA" (ByVal lpLibFileName As String) As LongPtr
Public Declare PtrSafe Function FreeLibrary Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hLibModule As LongPtr) As Long
#Else
Public Declare Function dllFunc1 Lib "MyDll32.dll" (ByVal FileName As String) As Long
Public Declare Function dllFunc2 Lib "MyDll32.dll" (ByVal session As Long, ByVal fieldname As String, ByVal Value As String) As Long
Public Declare Function dllFunc3 Lib "MyDll32.dll" (ByVal session As Long, ByVal context As String, ByVal result As String, ByVal result_buffer_size As Long, ByVal message As String, ByVal message_buffer_size As Long, ByVal fieldref As String, ByVal fieldref_buffer_size As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function dllFunc4 Lib "MyDll32.dll" (ByVal session As Long, ByVal context As String, ByVal fieldname As String, ByVal result As String, ByVal result_buffer_size As Long, ByVal message As String, ByVal message_buffer_size As Long, ByVal fieldref As String, ByVal fieldref_buffer_size As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function dllFunc5 Lib "MyDll32.dll" (ByVal session As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function SetEnvironmentVariable Lib "kernel32" Alias "SetEnvironmentVariableA" (ByVal lpName As String, ByVal lpValue As String) As Long
Public Declare Function LoadLibrary Lib "kernel32" Alias "LoadLibraryA" (ByVal lpLibFileName As String) As Long
Public Declare Function FreeLibrary Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hLibModule As Long) As Long
#End If
```

Class Module clsMyDll

```
Option Explicit

#If Win64 Then
    Dim hLib As LongPtr
#Else
    Dim hLib As Long
#End If

Public Sub DoSomeFunc1()
Dim x As Long
x = dllFunc1("Value") ' Senseless only example
End Sub

Public Sub DoSomeFunc2()
' Do stuff with this apie
End Sub
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Dim pathToDLL As String
    pathToDLL = ThisWorkbook.path & "\MyDlls" ' Folder below this workbook path
    Call SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", pathToDLL)
    #If Win64 Then
        hLib = LoadLibrary("MyDll64.dll")
    #Else
        hLib = LoadLibrary("MyDll32.dll")
    #End If
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    On Error Resume Next
 ' Do some more CleanUp here
 
 ' Now release
    If hLib <> 0 Then
        Call FreeLibrary(hLib)
        hLib = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Module mdlIni

```
Option Explicit
Public MyClassForDll As clsMyDll

Option Private Module

Public Sub IniClass()
MyClassForDll = New clsMyDll
End Sub

Public Sub CloseClass()
Set MyClassForDll = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Good to see you figured it out.